# calling Fortran from python

Tags: python, ubuntu, fortran, embedded-linux

I have a problem when I tried to call subroutin of Fortran from Python. I must run a complex code.

In the file main.f90, I run a program:

```
program main
 ....
end program main
```

In program main, there are a lot of subroutines. So It is so convenient for me to show code in here. I have an exact result, When I built and run on Ubuntu 18.04 with command:

```
>> gfortran main.f90 -o main
>>./main
```

However, when I change:

```
subroutine main()
...
end subroutine main
```

to call this function in python:

```
import main as m
m.main()
```

by command:

```
f2py -c main.f90 -m main
python mainPython.pu
```

My result is very different from the result that I get when I run a code with Fortran.

I do not understand why. Can you explain it for me? Are there any mistake in my code that create the difference.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: The approach of how you call Fortran routines from python is required.

Comment: Dear David Wu, I just edited my question. You can follow it, I expect your help so much

Comment: Just add a minimal example that reproduces the same issue.

Comment: Indeed, you need to define what "different" means and provide a small example (not necessarily the code that you don't want to share) that shows the problem

Comment: We need to see the program, or a similar code that produces the same type of error.